# Make columns equal heights

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on 2 columns made with Bootstrap 3. We cannot change to Bootstrap 4 at the moment, since we are having a webshop with over 100.000 products. So that is a project for the future, since we do not have time right now. Therefore solutions with solve the below problem with Bootstrap 4 is not an option right now.

At the moment I am working with Bootstrap 3. I am having some problems make my columns equal heights. The right is smaller than the left one.

Does anybody know a good solution, so the columns are having equal height - even if the viewport is changing? It does not matter when the viewport is mobile.

There is a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5wadx9pj/)

```css
.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
}

.padding-twocolumn-bg {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.business-left-img a img { 
    width: auto; 
    margin:auto 
}
.business-left {
    padding:75px 75px 40px 75px;
}
.classWithPad { 
    margin:8px; 
    padding:10px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border:1px solid #ebecf0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Section 7 -->
    <div class="section padding-twocolumn-bg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-6 business-left-img">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <p class="business-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <a><img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    <h2>AGA-Tools</h2>
                    <p>Name - Position</p>
                    <a href="tel+4587582106">+45 12 34 56 78</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-md-6">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3 class="sbp-align">Headline</h3>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            </a>
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Ansøg nu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.row [class*="col-"] {
    padding-right: 7.5px;
    padding-left: 7.5px;
}

.padding-twocolumn-bg {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.business-left-img a img { 
    width: auto; 
    margin:auto 
}
.business-left {
    padding:75px 75px 40px 75px;
}
.classWithPad { 
    margin:8px; 
    padding:10px; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border:1px solid #ebecf0;
    
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- Section 7 -->
    <div class="section padding-twocolumn-bg">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-md-6 business-left-img">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <p class="business-left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    <a><img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    <h2>AGA-Tools</h2>
                    <p>Name - Position</p>
                    <a href="tel+4587582106">+45 12 34 56 78</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center col-md-6">
                <div class="classWithPad">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h3 class="sbp-align">Headline</h3>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            </a>
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Ansøg nu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150" style="padding:10px;">
                            <h4 class="sbp-align">Subline</h4>
                            <p class="sbp-align">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                            <hr id="sbp-hr">
                            <a href="#">Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can add

```css
.classWithPad {
    height: 100%;
}
```

or

```css
.business-left {
  padding: 37px 75px 40px 75px;
}
```

You can do it in many different ways, by playing with the paddings and margins, but I think the `hieght: 100%` is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer @Pain. I cannot see any difference when I add the `.classWithPad {
    height: 100%;
}`

Comment: I added a snippet check it.

Comment: Ah yes I can see the difference on the fiddle, but not at my livesite

Comment: maybe a cache problem, try hard refresh.

Comment: try add this (#front .padding-twocolumn-bg .row {
    padding-bottom: 0px 
}) and add padding-bottom: 30px to .classWithPad

Comment: i just updated the code. Does not seem to have the effect on the page?

Comment: you have an extra <style>  in your html remove it

Comment: #front .padding-twocolumn-bg .row { 
       padding-bottom: 0px 
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 7.5px;
        padding-left: 7.5px;
    }
 
    .padding-twocolumn-bg {
        margin-bottom:30px;
    }
   .business-left-img a img { 
        width: auto; 
        margin:auto 
    }
    .business-left {
        padding:75px 75px 40px 75px;
    }
 

    /* TEST on 2 column */
    .classWithPad { margin:0px; padding:10px; background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #ebecf0;padding-bottom: 30px; height: 100%}

Comment: copy this and paste it inside the <stylle></style> (remove the old style)

Comment: Thanks @Pain. I just copy pasted the code, but still the same. Nothing is caching :-/

Comment: you have a <style> tag inside the <style> (this is unvalid)

Comment: Ok Weird. Is that a big screen you have? I have a laptop and try with different viewports and browsers: https://ibb.co/MgmgXx8
https://ibb.co/KKb9XH2

Comment: remove the style tag entirely and replace it with this `<style> #front .padding-twocolumn-bg .row { padding-bottom: 0px } .row [class*="col-"] { padding-right: 7.5px; padding-left: 7.5px; } .padding-twocolumn-bg { margin-bottom:30px; } .business-left-img a img { width: auto; margin:auto } .business-left { padding:75px 75px 40px 75px; } /* TEST on 2 column */ .classWithPad { margin:0px; padding:10px; background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #ebecf0;padding-bottom: 30px; height: 100%} </style>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216818/discussion-between-mk-dk-and-pain).